# How to make view responsive to mobile devices with bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap, so hoping someone can give me a little color around what I'm missing.  Basically, I've developed several views and when I narrow the browser window down past 768 X 1024 my elements automatically expand to 100% of the view and the images get all distorted.

Here is what it looks like at 768 X 1024:

[image]

And here when I shrink the browser further:

[image]

So, you can see that the nav menu and each tile is stretching to full 100% at this point.  What I would like is for the tiles and the menu to remain the same width when they stack. Here is the HTML for the navigation panel and the tiles:

[image]

CSS:

```
.typehead{
 text-align:center;
 /*height: 100px; */
 background: #3f3f3f;
 margin: -5px 0px -5px -5px !important;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.myborderwrap{
border: 1px solid #000000;
border-radius: 10px;    

}

.tiles{
padding-left: 50px !important;
margin-bottom: 25px;


}

.crystalcontainer{

padding: 15px 15px 5px 15px;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: -15px 15px 5px #888888;

}

.crystalname{
font-size: 12pt;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
word-wrap: break-word;  


}

.ratingrow{
text-align: center;
color: #007d7d;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
}

.add{

border-radius: 10px;
text-align: center;
padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
margin-top: 3px;
cursor:pointer;
background: #000000;
font-size: 12pt;    

}

.cdescwindow{

position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0px !important;
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.cdesccaption{
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
background:rgba(66, 139, 202, 0.75);
width:100%;
height:100%;

display: none;
text-align:center;
color:#fff !important;
z-index:2;
}

.crystaldescription{

padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 12pt;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="wrap">
<nav id="w029141" class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top mymenuhead navbar" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#w029141-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/devfront/index.php">
<div class="row">
<img width="155px" height="55px" alt="" src="img/CMLogoSnowflake.gif">
<span style="font-style: italic; color: #f9f31c; font-size: 10pt;"> beta</span>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div id="w029141-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul id="w13562" class="navbar-nav nav" style="margin-left: 100px;">
<li>
<a href="/devfront/index.php?r=dev">DEV</a>
</li>
<li class="active">
<a href="/devfront/index.php?r=find%2Fsearch">Subscribe</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
Publish
<b class="caret"></b>
</a>
<ul id="w226843" class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
<a tabindex="-1" href="/devfront/index.php?r=publish%2Fdashboard">My Published Crystals</a>
</li>
<li>
<a tabindex="-1" href="/devfront/index.php?r=publish%2Fselect-new">Publish New Crystal</a>
</li>
<li>
<a tabindex="-1" href="/devfront/index.php?r=publish%2Fprofile">Manage Profiles</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul id="w33960" class="navbar-nav nav">
<li>
<a href="/devfront/index.php?r=manage%2Fmanage">My Crystals</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="navbar-nav" style="padding-top:8px">
<div id="crystalcounter" class="badge" style="background:#ffff00; color:#000000; font-weight:bold;">2</div>
</div>
<ul id="w422097" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav">
<li>
<a href="/devfront/index.php?r=site%2Findex">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/devfront/index.php?r=site%2Fabout">About</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/devfront/index.php?r=profile%2Fview">My Profile</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-method="post" href="/devfront/index.php?r=site%2Flogout">Logout (scottjms)</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="mybackground">
<div class="container">
<div class="site-index">
<span id="soundspan"></span>
<input id="searchtype" type="hidden" value="0" name="type">
<input id="brandtype" type="hidden" value="0" name="btype">
<div class="text-left"> </div>
</div>
<div class="body-content">
<div class="row searcharea">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-5" style="padding-right:0px">
<input id="crystalsearchbar" class="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Find a crystal..." name="crystalsearch">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1" style="padding-left:0px">
<div style="align: left; height: 42px; background-color: #3333cc; padding-left: 12px; width:50px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;">
<i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" style="padding-top:5px; color:white;"></i>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-left:20px">
<a class="publishrouter" href="?r=publish/select-new">
I want to publish my own!
<i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3" style="margin:35px 0px">
<div class="panel panel-danger">
<div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;">
<h3 class="panel-title">
<div class="row typehead">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<h4 style="color: #80ffff">Explore Crystals</h4>
</div>
</div>
</h3>
</div>
<div class="table">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked kv-sidenav">
<li id="allheader" class="allheader">All Crystals</li>
<li id="header16" class="header">
<a class="kv-toggle" href="{url}">
<span class="opened" style="display:none">
<i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
</span>
<span class="closed">
<i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
</span>
Self Publishing
</a>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li id="subtype1" class="subtype text-primary" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 25px; cursor:pointer;">» Blog Updates</li>
<li id="subtype29" class="subtype text-primary" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 25px; cursor:pointer;">» Social Media Posts</li>
<li id="subtype30" class="subtype text-primary" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 25px; cursor:pointer;">» My Events</li>
<li id="subtype31" class="subtype text-primary" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 25px; cursor:pointer;">» Build Your Own</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="header18" class="header">
<a class="kv-toggle" href="{url}">
<span class="opened" style="display:none">
<i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
</span>
<span class="closed">
<i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
</span>
Local Interest
</a>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
<li id="subtype32" class="subtype text-primary" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 25px; cursor:pointer;">» Tonight's Dinner Specials</li>
<li id="subtype33" class="subtype text-primary" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 25px; cursor:pointer;">» Live Music Here</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<div class="row" style="padding-top:35px"></div>
<div id="crystal-container" class="findcrystals">
<div id="crystalcontainer88" class="col-sm-3 tiles">
<div class="myborderwrap">
<div class="crystalcontainer" style="border:4px solid #80ffff;">
<div class="row">
<div class="crystalname">Blog Updates</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="thumbnail cdescwindow">
<div class="caption cdesccaption" style="display: none;">
<div class="crystaldescription">Get updated when your ....</div>
</div>
<div class="brandlogo">
<img class="catelogueimage" alt="" src="img/crystallogos/RBsalnmeicnterfalsit84783dar93UQ.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row icons">
<div class="row ratingrow">Not Rated </div>
<div id="crystal88" class="add open" title="Subscribe"> Subscribe </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="crystalcontainer132" class="col-sm-3 tiles">
<div class="myborderwrap">
<div class="crystalcontainer" style="border:4px solid #80ffff;">
<div class="row">
<div class="crystalname">My Social Media Po..</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="thumbnail cdescwindow">
<div class="caption cdesccaption" style="display: none;">
<div class="crystaldescription">Any social..</div>
</div>
<div class="brandlogo">
<img class="catelogueimage" alt="" src="img/crystallogos/RBsalnmeicnterfalsit84783dar93UQ.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row icons">
<div class="row ratingrow">Not Rated </div>
<div id="crystal132" class="add open" title="Subscribe"> Subscribe </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="crystalcontainer133" class="col-sm-3 tiles">
<div class="myborderwrap">
<div class="crystalcontainer" style="border:4px solid #80ffff;">
<div class="row">
<div class="crystalname">My Events</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="thumbnail cdescwindow">
<div class="caption cdesccaption" style="display: none;">
<div class="crystaldescription">All of the upcoming...</div>
</div>
<div class="brandlogo">
<img class="catelogueimage" alt="" src="img/crystallogos/RBsalnmeicnterfalsit84783dar93UQ.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row icons">
<div class="row ratingrow">Not Rated </div>
<div id="crystal133" class="add open" title="Subscribe"> Subscribe </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="crystalcontainer134" class="col-sm-3 tiles">
<div class="myborderwrap">
<div class="crystalcontainer" style="border:4px solid #80ffff;">
<div class="row">
<div class="crystalname">Build Your Own</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="thumbnail cdescwindow">
<div class="caption cdesccaption">
<div class="crystaldescription">Any event..</div>
</div>
<div class="brandlogo">
<img class="catelogueimage" alt="" src="img/crystallogos/RBsalnmeicnterfalsit84783dar93UQ.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row icons">
<div class="row ratingrow">Not Rated </div>
<div id="crystal134" class="add open" title="Subscribe"> Subscribe </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="crystalcontainer135" class="col-sm-3 tiles">
<div class="myborderwrap">
<div class="crystalcontainer" style="border:4px solid #80ffff;">
<div class="row">
<div class="crystalname">Local Dinner Speci..</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="thumbnail cdescwindow">
<div class="caption cdesccaption" style="display: none;">
<div class="crystaldescription">Tonights dinner..</div>
</div>
<div class="brandlogo">
<img class="catelogueimage" alt="" src="img/crystallogos/RBsalnmeicnterfalsit84783dar93UQ.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row icons">
<div class="row ratingrow">Not Rated </div>
<div id="crystal135" class="add open" title="Subscribe"> Subscribe </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="crystalcontainer138" class="col-sm-3 tiles">
<div class="myborderwrap">
<div class="crystalcontainer" style="border:4px solid #80ffff;">
<div class="row">
<div class="crystalname">Local Live Music E..</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="thumbnail cdescwindow">
<div class="caption cdesccaption" style="display: none;">
<div class="crystaldescription">Live music events ..</div>
</div>
<div class="brandlogo">
<img class="catelogueimage" alt="" src="img/crystallogos/RBsalnmeicnterfalsit84783dar93UQ.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row icons">
<div class="row ratingrow">Not Rated </div>
<div id="crystal138" class="add open" title="Subscribe"> Subscribe </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="crystalcontainer145" class="col-sm-3 tiles">
<div class="myborderwrap">
<div class="crystalcontainer" style="border:4px solid #ffff00;">
<div class="row">
<div class="crystalname">Black Dog Dinner S..</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="thumbnail cdescwindow">
<div class="caption cdesccaption">
<div class="crystaldescription">Our daily ..</div>
</div>
<div class="brandlogo">
<img class="catelogueimage" alt="" src="img/crystallogos/2lAPaXs-EYT3iNNQFh0a3hxIl.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row icons">
<div class="row ratingrow">Not Rated </div>
<div id="crystal145" class="add branded" title="Subscribe"> Subscribe </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Please post the raw HTML and CSS

Comment: do you mean the view that is rendering this html?

Comment: The HTML code that you posted an image of, it would be easier for us to troubleshoot if you posted that raw HTML code as well as any CSS you may be applying to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only using COL-SM which only effects small screens. You need to add the class "col-XS" to tell bootstrap what to do on extra small screens. By default it is "col-xs-12" which stacks.

Here is the fiddle I made for you. You can see on an extra-small screen size the "tiles" are going to show 2 to a row. because i gave them this class:  `Col-xs-6`
https://jsfiddle.net/93bg9v2z/2/

edit: based on your request here is the new fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/93bg9v2z/3/

Comment: ok I wasn't sure if it was just that simple.  I'd really like to have at least 3 to a row on small screens and up.  Would there be a way to make that happen and then have them stack 1 to a row on mobile?

Comment: yes, change all the tile classes to col-sm-4 col-xs-12

since there are only 12 columns in the grid, this will make small screen tiles have a column width of 4, allowing on 3 per row. the col-xs-12 will do 1 per row on mobile screens. @Scott

Comment: oh I see now..you are actually adding the col-xs- class and keeping the col-sm- as well so it knows what to do on bigger screens.  That's the part that I didn't get.  Thank you!

Comment: @Scott correct! I edited my answer to include an example of this as well.